# How to load an image locally and display its contents using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want a valid code for how to load an image locally and display its contents.

I have tried several times but failed.

```
 <button class="btn " id="upload-file-button"> Upload Pictures <input accept="image/*" id="upload-file-input" multiple="" style="display:none;" type="file"> </button>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you tried that doesn't work.

Comment: <button class="btn " id="upload-file-button"> Upload Pictures
          <input accept="image/*" id="upload-file-input" multiple="" style="display:none;" type="file">
        </button>

Comment: You mean that you want to display a preview of the image the user just chosen? Also, please include the code in the question's body by editing the question..

Comment: yes i want that

Comment: You probably have seen this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/863110
or similar. If so, please post your code so we could try to understand what's wrong with it.